How to make python code fast for minimization?
The following code for minimization of a mechanical system works with no error.
However, it is slow and to me there are unnecessary steps or loops that make it heavy!
Would you make comment, and preferably a modified version of the code.
The code:
from os.path import join
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nu = 30
nv = 5
k = float(10)

def Us(i, j, uu):
    uu = uu.reshape((nu + 1, nv + 1))
    return i + np.sign(i) * uu[np.abs(i), j + nv]

def Vs(i, j, vv):
    vv = vv.reshape((nu + 1, nv + 1))
    return 2 * j + vv[np.abs(i), j + nv]

def Enrgy(varlbs):
    uu = varlbs[:(nu + 1) * (nv + 1)].reshape((nu + 1, nv + 1))
    vv = varlbs[(nu + 1) * (nv + 1) : 2 * (nu + 1) * (nv + 1)].reshape((nu + 1, nv + 1))
    sumsp = np.sum(np.fromiter(
        ((((Us(i + 1, j, uu) - Us(i, j, uu)) ** 2 + (Vs(i + 1, j, vv) - Vs(i, j, vv)) ** 2) ** (1/2) - 1) ** 2
            for i in range(-nu, nu)
            for j in range(-nv, 1)), dtype=float))
    return 0.5 * k * sumsp - .5 * Vs(0, -2, vv)

def con1(varlbs):
    uu = varlbs[:(nu + 1) * (nv + 1)].reshape((nu + 1, nv + 1))
    return np.array([uu[nu, j + nv] for j in range(-nv, 1)])

def con2(varlbs):
    vv = varlbs[(nu + 1) * (nv + 1) : 2 * (nu + 1) * (nv + 1)].reshape((nu + 1, nv + 1))
    return np.array([vv[i, 0] for i in range(0, nu)])

con12 = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda varlbs: con1(varlbs)}, {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda varlbs: con2(varlbs)}]

initialvals = np.zeros((2 * (nu + 1) * (nv + 1))).flatten()

minoutput = minimize(lambda varlbs: Enrgy(varlbs), initialvals, constraints=con12)

print(minoutput)

I tried use of sum (with no np.fromiter) instead np.sum.
I tried dropping reshape in definition of functions.
I tried even Sum by "sympy" (although not sure I used it correctly).
I expect code runs in 10 seconds instead 110 secs or more!

Does your function have a derivative? Providing a derivative to minimize() would make this function approximately 300 times faster, as it would no longer need to numerically differentiate the function.

No, it doesn't have any derv.

The primary thing I would suggest is avoiding the loops in Enrgy().
def Enrgy(varlbs):
    uu = varlbs[:(nu + 1) * (nv + 1)].reshape((nu + 1, nv + 1))
    vv = varlbs[(nu + 1) * (nv + 1) : 2 * (nu + 1) * (nv + 1)].reshape((nu + 1, nv + 1))
    i_array, j_array = np.meshgrid(range(-nu, nu), range(-nv, 1), sparse=True)
    term1 = (Us(i_array + 1, j_array, uu) - Us(i_array, j_array, uu)) ** 2
    term2 = (Vs(i_array + 1, j_array, vv) - Vs(i_array, j_array, vv)) ** 2
    inner = ((term1 + term2) ** (1/2) - 1).flatten()
    
    sumsp = np.dot(inner, inner)
    return 0.5 * k * sumsp - .5 * Vs(0, -2, vv)

This uses meshgrid() to get an array of indices which can be used in indexing operations to get all results from Us and Vs at once.
I also noticed redundant reshape operations:
def Us(i, j, uu):
    uu = uu.reshape((nu + 1, nv + 1))
    return i + np.sign(i) * uu[np.abs(i), j + nv]

def Vs(i, j, vv):
    vv = vv.reshape((nu + 1, nv + 1))
    return 2 * j + vv[np.abs(i), j + nv]

Here, vv and uu already have the correct shapes. (The reshape happened in Enrgy().) These reshape operations can be removed.
In con2, this is inefficient:
    return np.array([vv[i, 0] for i in range(0, nu)])

It would be faster to use vv[:, 0] to select the first column, and vv[:, 0][:-1] to drop the last value from that column.  (Assuming you meant to drop the last value. I can't tell if that's a bug.)
Benchmarking the two implementations, I find this version is about 50x faster.
Original
5.53 ms ± 71.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
Optimized
109 µs ± 418 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

I think further speedups are possible. Some areas you might want to look into:

The minimize() function will approximate your function's jacobian through numeric differentiation. This is really slow: for 1 dimension, it needs 1 extra call to your objective function to do this. For 372 dimensions, it needs 372 extra calls.
Writing this in Numba might speed this up.


Thanks dear Nick.
In fact the code runs much faster. However, even with original constraint "con2", the result by the new code is different. I mean the numbers by minimization are not the same by original and the modified one!
